# Change Input to image and make it clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I am trying to be able to make a "Select All" Toggle button with an image. This code works if you click the button on the left, but if you hide the button the image is not clickable.

How can I make the image clickable and remove the button on the right?

Here is my code:

```js
function togglecheckboxes(master,group){
 var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(group);
 for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
  var cb = document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id);
  cb.checked = master.checked;
 }
}
```

```css
/* this will remove box

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
 */
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
   
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-transition:.1s;
    -ms-transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
    -webkit-transition:.1s;
}
label.all {
    margin-bottom: -17px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbgroup1')">
    <label for="music">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label> <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1">
    <label for="music">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_2" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="2">
    <label for="music">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_3" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="3">
    <label for="music">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_4" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="4">
    <label for="music">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label>
</body>
```

Comment: Can u show sample in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label "for" attribute are set to the same and not targeting the input (checkbox).

Change the value (id of the input) and the image will be clickable.

```js
function togglecheckboxes(master,group){
 var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(group);
 for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
  var cb = document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id);
  cb.checked = master.checked;
 }
}
```

```css
/* this will remove box

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
 */
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
   
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-transition:.1s;
    -ms-transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
    -webkit-transition:.1s;
}
label.all {
    margin-bottom: -17px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbgroup1')">
    <label for="cbgroup1_master">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label> <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1">
    <label for="cb1_1">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_2" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="2">
    <label for="cb1_2">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_3" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="3">
    <label for="cb1_3">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_4" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="4">
    <label for="cb1_4">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change some markup

set check-box id attribute and `<label for>` same

---

for master

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbgroup1')">
    <label for="cbgroup1_master"> <!-- for attribute same as checkbox id -->
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label> <br><br>
```

---

for child

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1">
    <label for="cb1_1"> <!-- for attribute same as checkbox id -->
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label><br>
```

### [**jS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s1o5sy00/)

Answer (score 1):

The **for**-attribute on the label should have the **id** of the checkbox.
If the checkbox ID is "music", the **for**-attribute should be "music" as well.

```css
/* this will remove box

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
 */
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
   
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-transition:.1s;
    -ms-transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
    -webkit-transition:.1s;
}
label.all {
    margin-bottom: -17px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="music" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1">
    <label for="music">
        <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
    </label>
```